# Pascal - Writing Strange Characters

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I am attempting to write a comment stripper in pascal. I run my code and pass it a C source code file and it strips the comments from the file and prints the result to terminal.

I am fairly new to pascal. I am getting some very strange output and I cannot figure out why. The code checks for comments line by line and prints characters one at a time. The comment stripper is printing what seems to be random characters whenever it reaches the start of a new line. I am using pascals Write(Str[i]) function to print characters and WriteLn() once the end of a line is reached.

I have no idea why im receiving weird output. I am running Linux Mint and can compile and run my code, but I receive this strange output. I also tried running my code on a Mac and received a run-time error:

```
Program Path: ./Assignment1
File Name: lol.c
Runtime error 2 at $00011532
$00011532
$0002F7F6
$000113FD
$00011328
$00000002
```

Here is my code

```
program Assignment1;

uses
    Sysutils;

var UserFile    : TextFile;
   TString      : String;
   OLine        : String;
   i            : integer;
   isComment    : boolean;
   skip         : boolean;

begin

    {$I+}
   WriteLn('Program Path: ', ParamStr(0));
   WriteLn('File Name: ', ParamStr(1));

   Assign(UserFile, ParamStr(1) + '.c');
   Reset(UserFile);

   isComment := false;
   skip := true;

    Repeat

        Readln(UserFile, TString);

        for i:= 0 to ((Length(TString) - 1)) do
        begin
            if(skip) then
                begin
                    skip := false;
                    continue;
                end;


            if(isComment = false) Then
            begin

                if(TString[i] = '/') Then
                begin
                    if(TString[i+1] = '/') Then
                    begin
                        break;
                    end

                    else if(TString[i+1] = '*') Then
                    begin
                        isComment := true;
                        skip := true;
                        continue;
                    end;
                end;

                Write(TString[i]);
                if(i = Length(TString) - 1) Then
                    begin
                    Write(TString[i + 1]);
                    end;

            end

            else
            begin
                if(TString[i] = '*') Then
                begin
                    if(TString[i + 1] = '/') Then
                    begin
                        isComment := false;
                        skip := true;
                        continue;
                    end;
                end;
            end;

        end;

        WriteLn();

    Until Eof(UserFile);

end.
```

I receive random characters which range from standard keyboard symbols to unicode blocks such as the ones found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miscellaneous_Symbols_and_Pictographs).

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: In Pascal, strings are typically 1-based.

Comment: ``if(TString[i + 1]`` : could lead to a range error. you should rather accumulate an identifier and test its value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As 500 - Internal Server Error says, Pascal strings are 1-based.  Your references to slot zero are returning garbage.  If these are 256-byte strings you're getting the length code, I don't recall the memory layout of the pointer-based strings to know what you're getting in that case.  You're also losing the last character of every string because of this.

Beyond that I see a definite bug:  Look at what happens with a line ending in /

I also do not understand this:

```
            if(i = Length(TString) - 1) Then
                begin
                Write(TString[i + 1]);
                end;
```

It seems to me it's writing an extra character but I'm not sure.

Comment: 1-based was what was causing my problems. Code ending in a '/' would cause problems. For simplicity, I assume all C code is properly formatted. I believe there is no way C code can end in a '/' and compile. Also, because I index TString using i + 1 sometimes, I can only run `i = 0 to Length(TString) - 1`.  This means `TString[Length(TString)]` must be printed when `i = Length(TString) - 1`. Thanks for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: @MattyChuck That's not the way programming works.  You can't just ignore characters because sometimes referring to them blows up.  You have to fix your logic instead.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding, im not ignoring any characters. If my second last character is not in a comment or the start of a comment, my last character in the line surely cannot be either. Anyways, my comment stripper is working flawlessly at this point. but thanks for the concern.

Comment: @MattyChuck Oh, I see what you're doing--you're not checking the last character at all.